# Angular directives recognized as html form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have made my own directive that act as a input element with contenteditable attribute.
My problem is that the element is not recognized by jQuery as a element.
If i do

> $('form').serialize()

or

> document.getElementById("form").elements

My element will not show up in both functions.
Does someone know why ? and how to fix it ?

Comment: Show relevant code of that directive

Comment: I guess this can't be serialize like this and what this has to do with angularjs??

Comment: With Angular one typically does not serialize the DOM elements, but rather works with the model. If you have a bunch of input controls with `ng-model="form.p1"`, then all you need is the object `$scope.form`.

Comment: Show your directive structure. You no need to use JQuery here since the element is directly accessible in directive and jQlite does everything that jQuery do

Comment: I want to serialize it because i need to get all the values and compare them with there init value.
If i would use $scope.form and the ngmodel is empty it will first be undefined and later on if you make the input field empty you get a empty sting..

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/JKml1yHSxc6csMEKOjik?p=preview

Comment: @user3093036, not sure what you mean. Why is this a problem that empty input field yields an empty string. At any rate, you need to reason in terms of models, not DOM. If your directive works correctly - i.e. it uses the `ng-model` framework (see [example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#custom-control-example)) - then all the data is in the model.

Answer (score 1):

The `serialize` method of jQuery does not include `contenteditable` elements. So you can't read your element like this.

Many WYSIWYG html editor use a trick with a hidden `textarea`. They synchronize the content of the `contenteditable` inner html with the content of the `textarea`. The `serialize` jQuery method will see the `textarea` and use it.

Since you are using Angular, it's pretty easy to synchronise two elements with the same model.